# appium TouchAction press and moveTo scrolling method not working on Android 8.1

Tags: java, android, automation, appium, ui-automation

i'm using appium 1.13.0 to try to scroll through a native android app on a samsung galaxy note 9 on android 8.1 with this method here

```
new TouchAction(driver).press(PointOption.point(943, 1090)).moveTo(PointOption.point(70, 1090)).release().perform();
```

but it doesn't seem to be working, the screen doesn't move at all.

sending this scroll input from the adb shell command line does work though

```
adb shell input swipe 500 100 500 300
```

but I really need to be able to send a scroll event through appium, not the command line.

can anyone help out?

Comment: Facing same issue, any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely that you forgot to put a waitoptions.

`touchAction.press(PointOption.point(943, 1090)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(1000)).moveTo(PointOption.point(70, 1090)).release().perform();`

Comment: I tried this and instead of scroll only flickering is happening without throwing any exception.

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan : Show your code so that we understand what you have done.

Comment: Adding that wait action did the job for me. Thanks!

Comment: Only Working for me in debug, i had increased the time but still it not working when run normally